# How to Assigning a variable returned in PHP to a variable in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to make queries with Baraer token in an api system working with OAuth 2. Since the token is renewed every 24 hours, I developed a php code that can constantly renew the expired token. My PHP code returns the current token.
How can I get this data via Flutter? It simply returns it. No JSON expression, no api. A blank page and a variable returned in the background.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from your question, there is a php endpoint (maybe POST), that refresh a token and flutter need to fetch the token data to a variable. If this is the case, you can just do a simple HTTP request to that server endpoint (using an HTTP client like [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)), and read the body of the response to a variable.